# Is it possible to use the alignment of a generic type in a transparent struct?

Tags: rust, memory

I'm trying to build a Rust type with the same layout as some generic type `T`, but copying the alignment of another type `A`:

```rust
/// Copy the alignment of `A` (if larger than the alignment of `T`),
/// otherwise has the exact same memory layout as `T`.
#[repr(transparent)]
struct WithAlignment<T, A> {
    /// Zero-sized field with the alignment of `A`
    _alignment: [A; 0],

    /// Actual data
    data: T, 
}
```

However, the compiler seems to be unable to understand that `_alignment` is a zero-sized field:

```
error[E0690]: transparent struct needs at most one non-zero-sized field, but has 2
 --> src/lib.rs:4:1
  |
4 | struct WithAlignment<T, A> {
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ needs at most one non-zero-sized field, but has 2
5 |     /// Zero-sized field with the alignment of `A`
6 |     _alignment: [A; 0],
  |     ------------------ this field is non-zero-sized
...
9 |     data: T, 
  |     ------- this field is non-zero-sized
```

Is there any way to tell the compiler that the `_alignment` field should have the same alignment as `A`, but zero size, in a way that would work with `#[repr(transparent)]`?

Comment: @Stargateur I'm trying to build a "generic non-allocating type-erased future" similar in functionality to `Box<dyn Future>`. I want to avoid borrowing and instead have the type own the contained futures, so I need to allocate memory on the stack with a specific size and alignment sufficient to hold these futures that are only known at runtime. As for why I'm doing _that_, it's mostly as a challenge for myself, not for any particular practical purposes.

Comment: what about union or enum ?

Answer (score 3):

This is not possible.
[`repr(transparent)`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/other-reprs.html?highlight=align#reprtransparent) enforces that the ABI of the wrapped struct (`T`) is the same as the one for the wrapper (`WithAlignment`).

Alignment is a part of the ABI contract, and part of the ['layout'](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/alloc/struct.Layout.html).

Even the following declaration is already [illegal](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/1758-repr-transparent.md#motivation):

```rust
#[repr(transparent, align = "128")]
struct BogusAlign(f64);
```

---

A possible struct that's close to what you described would be:

```rust
#[repr(C)]
struct WithAlignment<T, A> {
    // actual data, guaranteed to be at offset 0 due to `repr(C)`
    data: T, 

    // Zero-sized field to guarantee a minimum alignment of `A`
    _alignment: [A; 0], 
}
```

This struct is guaranteed (due to [`repr(C)`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/other-reprs.html#reprc)) to have

- A contained `T` at offset 0
- Alignment `max(align_of::<T>(), align_of::<A>())`
- Size `lcm(size_of::<T>(), align_of::<A>())`
  (lcm meaning [lowest common multiple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_common_multiple))

Note that the field order is inversed from the struct suggested in your own anser @Frxstrem. That version would allow the compiler to insert padding before `data`, preventing direct pointer
casts from `T` to `WithAlignment<T, A>`.

Answer (score 3):

As described in [this issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/98064) (and pointed out by @ChrisB), the problem is that the error message is misleading: `#[repr(transparent)]` can only work if there is a single field with non-zero size *or aligment other than 1*. In this case there's only non-zero-sized field, but the `_alignment` field may have an alignment other than 1, so `#[repr(transparent)]` cannot be used.

The simplest workaround is to just use `#[repr(C)]` instead. Specifically, the [reference](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/other-reprs.html?highlight=align#reprc) points out that:

> ZSTs are still zero-sized, even though this is not a standard behavior in C, and is explicitly contrary to the behavior of an empty type in C++, which says they should still consume a byte of space.

This will lead to the type having the same memory layout, although the behavior is slightly different than `#[repr(transparent)]`, [especially when dealing with FFI](https://rust-lang.github.io/unsafe-code-guidelines/layout/structs-and-tuples.html#function-call-abi-compatibility).

```rust
#[repr(C)]
struct WithAlignment<T, A> {
    /// Zero-sized field with the alignment of `A`
    _alignment: [A; 0],

    /// Actual data
    data: T, 
}
```